# Label highways in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, arcgis-10.3

Is the labeling toolbar the correct tool to use in ArcMap for labeling highways? I am trying to label interstates and am not having success.

I am trying to create a text box or label to place on the highways to identify between different highways.

Both highways are the same color in the map key. Both of the interstates are also the same color on the map and must remain that way.

I do not want to label the interstate in the table of contents.

I would like to label the interstates on the map itself.

The interstates lead to different directions and must be the same color to match the map key.

ArcMap version 10.3

Comment: If you're just trying to figure out how to label features at all in ArcMap: double-click on the layer's name in the table of contents (or right-click > properties), and then select the label tab. It's pretty self-explanatory from there. You can do it via the labeling toolbar, but it's just going to overwhelm you for now.

Comment: Both highways are the same color in the map key. However, the interstates lead to different directions.  << what does that mean???

Comment: http://help.arcgis.com/En/Arcgisdesktop/10.0/Help/index.html#/Essential_labeling_concepts/00s80000000t000000/

Comment: Is there something special about the roads data that you're using, or are you more generally asking about how to get started with labeling in ArcMap?

Comment: I think including a picture of what you are trying to achieve would help make what you are asking clearer.

Answer (score 1):

In the Labels tab in Layer Properties, click the Method drop down at the top and select "Define Classes of features and label each class differently". Here, you can click the Add button and add "I", for example. Then you can select the field you wish to label, which might be a Highway Number field in your attribute table. Then, you can click the Symbol button and scroll down until you see Interstate.

You can repeat this for U.S. Highways and State Highways by simply clicking the Add button and changing the Label Field and Symbol accordingly.

Comment: user68937, if this answer was sufficient to help you with the problem, would you be so kind as to mark my answer correct? If not, could you provide more clarity to help solve the question? Thanks mate!